MariaDB ColumnStore Internal error: CAL0001: Insert Failed: a BRM Begin copy error
I'm using ColumnStore 11.1.4-MariaDB-1:11.1.4+maria~deb12 and while I'm doing many inserts (one by one) I gained this type of error:
1815 - Internal error: CAL0001: Insert Failed:  MCS-2009: Unable to perform the insert operation because DMLProc batchinsert with PID 1360617 is currently holding the table lock for session 316.
And I tried to make all INSERT queries like
START TRANSACTION ;

INSERT INTO transactions (id, park_id, event_at, category_id, amount, description, driver_id)
VALUES
  ( 5465425840062, 2, '2021-11-30 07:33:25', 'partner_ride_fee', -88.4, 'Комиссия партнёра по заказу', 'db8b4a66d9904b0ca3677cd945e7a45b');

COMMIT;

to iniate transaction and commit it, but now I'm stuck with this error:
CAL0001: Insert Failed: a BRM Begin copy error.
while executing this:
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO transactions ( id, park_id, event_at, category_id, amount, description, driver_id, order_id, short_order_id, dispatcher_name )
VALUES
  ( 15549683950031, 1, '2024-05-15 09:14:39', 'platform_ride_fee', - 82, 
  'Комиссия сервиса по заказу Общеобразовательная средняя школа №130, Шымкент, микрорайон Астана', '355f17ac1c5b5884033ae4a8f4334200', '4a20286d4cdec7d28ee3f192ab36b075', 12214134, NULL); 
COMMIT;

Is there any suggestions how can I prevent errors while inserts are executing? Should I do something like
INSERT transactions ( id, park_id, event_at, category_id, amount, description, driver_id, order_id, short_order_id, dispatcher_name )
     VALUES (),
            (),
            ()

instead? Or what?

The wording of the error message implies that some other query is running and blocking the one-row INSERT that you presented.  SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; may make that obvious.

@RickJames well that's what i thought first but here is what  SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST showing: Id User Host db Command Time State Info Progress
301 ismail 127.0.0.1:53480 fleetsoft Query 0 starting SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST 0

ANALYZE TABLE showing two errors for the same table: Internal error: MCS-2033: Error occurred when calling system catalog. and Unknown - internal error 1815 during operation

Hi @IsmailAkhmedov, what is the reason for doing single row inserts per transaction? Ideally you should be batching as many inserts together as you can to minimize locks. Do the inserts eventually succeed?

The reason was the lack of RAM on server  {}  AsynchronousMetrics: MemoryTracking: was 38.43 GiB, peak 38.43 GiB, free memory in arenas 12.34 GiB, will set to 26.69 GiB (RSS), difference: -11.74 GiB
